# Can anyone post a working config for hdmi out Dell XPs 15 L502x with Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, nvidia, bumblebee, optimus, hybrid-graphics

I have a Dell XPS 15 [L502x]. it comes with an Nvidia GeForce GT525 GPU card.

It's an Optimus laptop so an Intel card powers the main display but the hdmi out port connects to the Nvidia card.

I have never had the HDMI out work in Fedora and would like to rectify that.

Before I go back down the various rabbit-holes around optimus, bumblebee, nvidia, nouveau, Wayland and xorg I would like to find someone who has it working - just to see what they use.

If you have a Dell L502x running Fedora 25 and you have your HDMI out running please let me know. It would be great if you could post your working config.

If you run a different flavour of linux I would also be interested.

If you could take follow on questions that would be great!

disclosure: I asked this question a couple of days ago on ask.fedoraproject [https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/97486/does-anyone-have-hdmi-out-working-on-dell-xps-15-l502x-with-fedora-25/] but there hasn't been any response so I am castingmy net a bit wider. I hope that's ok.

Comment: I have a Dell XPS L502x having Nvidia GeForce GT540M card running with Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried the proprietary tested driver that comes along with the distribution also tested the Noveau Xorg one but no luck. So, using the intel card as of now. So, you are not the only one on earth having this problem. I join the group.Looking for the configuration :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is that no, no-one can post a working config for hdmi out on a Dell L502x laptop running Fedora 25.

That's a real pain.

I'll get back to this eventually and when i have a working config I will share it here for others.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/) and I think it will provide you with the necessary steps to install all the drivers and packages you'd need for HDMI support. There are tons of comments as well from people that show what nvdia graphics card they're using, the drivers they installed, problems they had with setup, and lots of other useful information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking this out. I am afraid this won't work. My laptop has two video cards - it's an Optimus set up and this tutorial specifically doesn't apply. [See point 1.2].
Thanks again.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Have you gotten it to work with older versions of fedora? If your

Comment: my bad I ended that way too early. If you're able to backup your current setup and then run some tests on earlier versions of fedora maybe you can isolate the problem by checking out differences in each Journal.

Comment: Here's a setup with Optimus configured on Fedora 17 & 18. https://duxyng.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/finally-working-nvidia-optimus-on-fedora/

Comment: I ahve often installed Optimus adn can successfully run glxgears with it. I have never had HDMi out working.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry to spam you with comments, but I think this time it will work with this setup. It involves using bumblebee but if you're willing to give it a shot the documentation is great. There is a section specifically for using multiple monitors at whatever resolution you need. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to be helpful. 

However my original posit isn't looking for tutorials or how-tos. Instead I am looking for people who have the same laptop as me and who have successfully got their HDMI out working to identify themselves.

I have looked at this page previously and my setup still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

a palliative solution, which works for me, is to reboot with the HDMI cable plugged in - then Fedora recognizes the second display and the video output can be redirected.

Comment: Hi Pavel, Thanks for taking the time to reply. I have tried this but it hasn't worked for me unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Jack, sorry to hear that ... just to make sure - did you have the external display turned on while rebooting?

Comment: Yep, I did indeed. Do you have an L502x Pavel? I would be curious what your config files are - I may have overwritten / compromised mine while trying to implement different solutions.

Comment: Hi Jack, I have L511z but the same video card, GT 525M - thought the behaviour would be the same. Next thing to check is the driver. With F25 I don't see nouveau being even tried -  intel driver takes over. I migrated from F23, F23 kernel was loading nouveau and I didn't find a reason for the change. Moreover, an attempt to force using nouveau (via .conf)  results in the graphics card not being recognized. Which driver do you get loaded under F25 ?

Comment: I have been trying to use bumblebee with the unfree nvidia driver as per https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee . I guess the nouveau driver must kick in when you use hdmi out though?

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on Arch Linux on this very laptop. I simply use nouveau drivers. The HDMI (projector) gets detected when I plug in the HDMI cable.

The problem is that with this solution, the Nvidia card is on at all times, which causes the system run hotter and the fan is being loud constantly. The solution to this problem is to install proprietary drivers with bumblebee or disable Nvidia card with "rmod nouveau", but this breaks HDMI.

However, if the fan does not bother you, pure nouveau is your solution.